# Drawings Map app coordinates WGS84

Tags: c#, graphics, maps

How to deal with big, WGS84 points coordinates?

What I think, I can do, is to translate world (WGS84) points, to points on screen in pixels. Is it a good way? It still doesn't work corectly because big zoom is needed, and I would have to change unit from meters to milimeters (but how? just multiplying the x, and y of points?).

Comment: If you want to display large areas, you need a map projection, such as a Transverse Mercator, because a simple vector transform can't correctly transform cylindrical coordinates to a flat surface. Show the code you use to convert from WGS84 to grid at the moment.

Comment: I don't have it yet. Right now I'm just subtracting the corner of window coordinates from the drawing points coordinates. So as you can see, I have no idea how to get to it. Could you explain, or even better show me some documentations?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very simplistic approach for this mapping problem. Geographers will probably cry about this, but it works quite well in practice as long as the coordinates are below about 70° latitude and the size of the window is not too big. Also, don't try to directly map large objects (such as very long lines) only using their start and end points.

```
public PointF GeoCoordToPixel(IGeographicPosition geoPos)
{
    double tempLong = geoPos.Longitude;
    if (tempLong > CenterPos.Longitude && (tempLong - CenterPos.Longitude) > 180)
    {
        // the position is to the left, over the antimeridian
        tempLong = tempLong - 360;
    }

    if (tempLong < CenterPos.Longitude && (CenterPos.Longitude - tempLong) > 180)
    {
        // the position is to the right, over the antimeridian
        tempLong = tempLong + 360;
    }

    PointF pt = new PointF(
        (float)((tempLong - LongitudeOfOrigin) / LongitudeIncrement),
        (float)((-geoPos.Latitude + LatitudeOfOrigin) / LatitudeIncrement));

    return pt;
}
```

with CenterPos = Center of window; LatituteOfOrigin / LongitudeOfOrigin = Top left position of window; LongitudeIncrement / LatitudeIncrement = Scale of view. Their relation is:

```
LatitudeOfOrigin = CenterPos.Latitude + (m_drawingBuffer.Height / 2.0 * LatitudeIncrement);
LongitudeOfOrigin = CenterPos.Longitude - (m_drawingBuffer.Width / 2.0 * LongitudeIncrement);
```

and the inverse:

```
public CGeographicPosition PixelToGeoCoord(PointF pt)
{
     double latitude = -(pt.Y * LatitudeIncrement) + LatitudeOfOrigin;
     double longitude = (pt.X * LongitudeIncrement) + LongitudeOfOrigin;
     if (longitude > 180)
     {
         longitude -= 360;
     }

     return (new CGeographicPosition(latitude, longitude, 0));
}
```

Not really difficult, is it?